# Could 'Me gusta *él, pero no*...' be heard as 'Me gusta *el perro, no*...'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronunciación

If somebody said:

> Me gusta **él, pero no** su grupo de amigos <sub>I like **him, but** not his group of friends</sub>

could it be heard as this?

> Me gusta **el perro, no** su grupo de amigos <sub>I like **the dog, not** his group of friends</sub>

If not, why not?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd-nefL-jyQ

Comment: **Pero** and **perro** are not pronounced the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be spoken on purpose to make it sound confusing, if you were telling a joke, for example. But in normal speaking, they sound quite different. There are two main differences:

1. Stress and rhythm. They will sound more or less:

> /me-gús-ta-él/ /pe-ro-nó-su-grú-po-dea-mí-gos/
>
> /me-gús-tael-pé-rro/ /nó-su-grú-po-dea-mí-gos/

Note how the stresses and the pauses are in different places. Also the article `el` is joined with the previous syllable, while the pronoun `él` is vocalized separately.

2. The words `pero` and `perro` sound quite different to a native speaker. The `rr` can be difficult to realize for a foreigner, or for natives with speech disorders.

It is worth noting that in writing the confusion is avoided by three differences:

1. The comma is in a different place.
2. The `rr` vs `r`.
3. The pronoun `él` does have an accent over the `é` while the article `el` does not.

Comment: Well explained. Pero and Perro doesn't sound **quite** different in Spain, they sound **very** different, except in the speech disorders you mentioned (well spotted). I don't think there's much difference in pronunciation between "el" and "él", though.

Comment: @Flamma: Well, "el" and "él" both have the same phonemes /e/+/l/. But "él" is tonic while "el" is atonic, that changes the rythm and the phonetic _syllabation_.

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante improbable que se confundan. La pronunciación entre *el* / **él** y *pero* / **perro** es bastante distinta, además de que la entonación cambia,se hace una pequeña pausa (representada por la coma).

Y centrándose en el significado, también es bastante improbable hacer una frase hablando del grupo de amigos de un perro.

Answer (score 1):

no en español estandar, porque son fonemas diferentes.

[ɾ] raro; pero; bravo; tronco; amor; comer

[r] raro; perro

no estoy seguro si en algunas zonas caribeñas puede acontecer.

Answer (score 1):

well, "Perro" is pronounced very diferent to "pero", so is not going to be misunderstood if you say it well

look, 
this is how you pronounce "perro"(dog) http://es.forvo.com/word/perro/

and this is how you pronounce pero http://es.forvo.com/word/pero/

easy...